# Calculating cosine in C++ with taylor series and approximation input

Tags: c++

Good evening, I am trying to calculate the cosine but i don't know where I am wrong. The results are imprecise and with wrong sign (-0.54 instead of 0.5 for a 60 degrees angle) even when the entered approximation is very high (i.e., 0.000001); for an angle of 30 degrees, no result is shown but the code is still running (i think the while loop does not end).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double fact (int);
double eps;
double PI=3.141592654;
double fact (int num){
if (num==0 || num==1)
    return 1;
else
    return num*fact(num-1);
}
int main(){
double deg;
    double rad;
    double term=0.0;
    double sum=0.0;
    double cosine=0.0;
    int i=1;
    cout<<"You have chosen to calculate the cosine. Insert degrees of the   desired angle: \n"; 
    cin>>deg;
    rad=(PI/180)*deg;
    cout<<"Value from the c++ library is: \n"<<cos(rad);
    cout<<"\nProceeding to cosine calculation, insert desired approximation here: \n";
    cin>>eps;
    while ((cos(rad)-fabs(cosine))>eps){
    term=pow(rad,2*i)*((pow(-1.0,i))/fact(2*i));
    sum+=term;
    i++;
    cosine=sum;
    }
    cout<<"Value of cosine is: "<<cosine;
}
```

What could I do to correct these errors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `M_PI` instead of defining PI yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line while monitoring the variables and their values.

Comment: @ChrisStathis How will he learn how to write programs that implement series if he just uses a predefined constant?

Comment: Your `while` condition needs to use the absolute value of the difference. Otherwise it will stop when the difference is negative, even if it's much bigger than epsilon.

Comment: Thanks, I figured the error and redefined pi. I also changed the counter start and now the code works fine.

Comment: @ChrisStathis: M_PI is a non-portable (not to mention ugly) POSIX thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error lies here:

```
while ((cos(rad)-fabs(cosine))>eps){
```

Probably it should be

```
while (fabs(cos(rad)-cosine)>eps){
```

But in reality to determinate precision people use difference between current and previous approximations.

Comment: I think your last sentence deserves more emphasis. As it stands, his code depends on already knowing the correct value in order to compute the correct value, which is generally pretty useless. For practical use, you need to be able to calculate a value without already knowing the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply: in that case, could I use, for example, the absolute value of the n-term to stop repetition (I. E. While (fabs(sen(rad))>eps)? Anyway, I  had to write code code this way because it was asked to determine the value of the cosine by confronting it with the library value.

Comment: Disclaimer: I learned numerical analysis more than 5 years ago, and do not use it at work.  @Fr52 `eps` is required precision of result. So by definition it is `|x - x*| < eps`, where x* is true value that we don't know. There are different ways to estimate current error, and they depends on algorithm that you use. I couldn't find such estimation for Taylor series, so you can try simple but rough formula `|x[k] - x[k-1]| < eps`. In your program it can be implemented as `do { /* your current loop body */ } while (fabs(term) < eps);` To learn more about this topic, google _stopping criterion_.

Comment: Of course it should be `do { /* your current loop body */ } while (fabs(term) > eps);` By the way, algorithm can converge too slowly, or even diverge. To catch this case there should be limit on maximum number of iterations.